# ALSA programming: how to stop immediately

Tags: c, linux, audio, alsa

I am building an audio app with playback and stop features. Function playaudio() is for playback, stopaudio() is for stop. The expected file format is just WAV.

The main implementation of playaudio() is as below:

```
playaudio()
{
... ...
    int err = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
    if ( err < 0 )
    {
       printf("SCM open failed: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));                
       exit(err);
    }

    while ( 0 < numOfFrames) {
        ... ...
        ssize_t frames = snd_pcm_writei(handle, &buffer[0], periodSize);
        ... ...
    }

    snd_pcm_drain(handle);
    snd_pcm_close(handle);
}

stopaudio()
{
    snd_pcm_drop( m_handle );
}
```

While audio playing back, program is blocked at the line of snd_pcm_drain(handle); until playback completion. During period, I expect to stop audio play. My action is to click a stop button on UI and call snd_pcm_drop( m_handle ) finally. Voice was actually stopped, but the programm running is still staying at the line of snd_pcm_drain(handle) untils several seconds later which is the play time of the played audio file.

My question is:
how to make snd_pcm_drain's waiting over immmediately once stop action was performed?
If not, is there any other way to implement immediate stop with keeping playaudio function waiting for playback completion?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How are you calling another function while `snd_pcm_drain` is active? With threads? Did you read [the documentation](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/SMP_Design)?

Comment: another stopaudio() is called by JNI from java code. In java swing UI, I have a JButton for audio stop. In the click event of the JButton, the C code stopaudio() is called via JNI finally which snd_pcm_drain is active. I haven't read the documentation. I will go ahead. Thank you for your sharing.